# CSS filter:url(#inlinesvg), How to change filter property value per instance?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I want to apply a svg filter to different elements, but for the different elements I want to adjust the value of a certain property. Is there a way to pass a variable for each instance?

I know I can set a variable to the filter itself, but then it will change the original and applies that to all instances.

Here my example ([codepen](https://codepen.io/MarkBoots/pen/qBmgzrR)). I'd like to add a different 'lighting-color' per instance
Is there a way to accomplish this without creating multiple filters?

```css
.paper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  filter: url(#paper-texture);
}
.paper.blue { --paper-color: blue; } /*does not work*/
.paper.red { --paper-color: red; } /*does not work*/

#paper-texture { /*effects the original filter for all instances*/
  --paper-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="paper blue"></div>
<div class="paper red"></div>

<!-- svg  -->
<svg width="0" height="0"> 
  <devs>
    <!-- paper-texture -->
    <filter id='paper-texture' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height="100%">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency='0.03' result='noise' numOctaves="5" />
      <feDiffuseLighting in='noise' lighting-color="var(--paper-color)" surfaceScale='2'>
        <feDistantLight azimuth='30' elevation='60' />
      </feDiffuseLighting>
    </filter>
  </devs>
</svg>
```

Comment: What's wrong with creating multiple filters?

Comment: I'm going to have much more colors of these 'paper'-textures. Later on the colors will even be generated with JS and I'd like to have unlimited options

Comment: generating the filters with JS will give you unlimited options.

Comment: Yea, allready knew, will keep that in mind as a backup. But for now I want to know if there is there no other option that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Is your filter working ? Even if you hardcode the value it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: There is no way to pass a parameter to a SVG filter. You have to create one filter per color.

Comment: Ohw, now i see. In firefox the filter (hard coded value) does work, but not in Chrome. I have to rethink what I want and need